# Create Custom cloudwatch metrics Based On IoT Sensor Data

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-iot-core

Need to know, how to  create custom log metric based on below scenario.

I have send my AWS IoT shadow data(when specified IoT Rule met) to cloudwatch log group. It contains

```
{ 
    " sensorName" : "sensorOne",
     "faultCode" : 102
}
```

- I want to send cloudwatch alarm **if one of our sensors sent above data, 3 times, within 5 min**.

Ex:

```
{ " sensorName" : "sensorOne", "faultCode" : 102  }
{ " sensorName" : "sensorOne", "faultCode" : 102  }
{ " sensorName" : "sensorOne", "faultCode" : 102  }
```

or

```
{ " sensorName" : "sensorTwo", "faultCode" : 102  }
{ " sensorName" : "sensorTwo", "faultCode" : 102  }
{ " sensorName" : "sensorTwo", "faultCode" : 102  }
```

- But currently I could not achieve that, because I **couldn't find** any method to **group logs by sensorName** (when create my custom metric). So alarm triggered based on aggregated count (sum of all messages, irrespective of specific sensor).

Ex: Alarm trigger for below set of log objects even they come from two different sensors (which is not expected).

```
   { " sensorName" : "sensorOne", "faultCode" : 102  }
   { " sensorName" : "sensorOne", "faultCode" : 102  }
   { " sensorName" : "sensorTwo", "faultCode" : 102  }
```

**Is that possible to do that with cloudwatch? Or any other recommended way to do this?**

Note: [Metric filter method work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html), but since we have 1000 iot devices, we need to create 1000 metric filters if we follow that approach.So I am looking for better approach.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch Metric filters now support dimensions on custom metrics. “SensorName”:$.sensorName specifies the metric dimension.